# How can I automatically post on my wordpress website photos that I took in my iPad?

Tags: ipad, wordpress, photo-gallery

The idea is to post into a Gallery on my website photos that I took with my iPad automatically using plugins. Or a workaround to achieve that functionality.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a wordpress app for ios and android that may help you https://apps.wordpress.org/

Comment: Thank you @allen6131. I will give a loot at it.

Comment: This app does not give me that functionality. It has to be something that allow me to take pictures and uploaded automatically, so people would be able to download them from my website.

Comment: as in when you take the picture it would automatically upload to your wordpress site with a download link ?

Comment: Yes, so people can Download their pictures anytime. And all pictures are posted in the Gallery for exhibition.